# Add specific element at specific location with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
    <ns0:Message1>
        <ns:sap_order_status xmlns:ns="http://orders.com">
            <row>
                <message_name/>
                <message_num/>
                <order_id/>
            </row>
        </ns:sap_order_status>
    </ns0:Message1>
</ns0:Messages>
```

I need my xml to look like this with a second sap_order_status after the first one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
    <ns0:Message1>
        <ns:sap_order_status xmlns:ns="http://orders.com">
            **<sap_order_status>**
                <row>
                    <message_name/>
                    <message_num/>
                    <order_id/>
                </row>
            **</sap_order_status>**
        </ns:sap_order_status>
    </ns0:Message1>
</ns0:Messages>
```

I got help in the past for previous messages, but this one is so different that I can't adjust the XSL.

Comment: How exactly is this "so different" from your previous question?

Comment: The XSL doesn't work, I guess that if it was the same the XSL would work?
I tried to run it, but what I got was 2 root element Messages and not sap_order_status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only real difference with your previous question ([Remove prefix from element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56461228/remove-prefix-from-element)) is that you are no longer dealing with the root element, but a descendant.

You just need to learn about the [identity template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), which will handle copy the existing elements before it gets to the one you do need to modify.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, instead of having a template matching the root element, you have a template matching the node you wish to append a new child to:

```
<xsl:template match="ns:sap_order_status">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The `ns:` prefixed would be declared on the `xsl:stylesheet` element.

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:ns="http://orders.com">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ns:sap_order_status">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes, it works! What I tried, was to change the way to get the root node
    `<xsl:variable name="topNode" select="name(/Message)"/>`
But that's because I don't really know what I'm doing.
Your code works great! Thanks a lot!